# Post build step in Maven

Tags: java, maven

How can we add a post step in a Maven build?

There is a simple java that contain only avro schemas and after the project is built I would want to iterate through each schema file and register it to a schema registry via REST.

Essentially, after the project builds we want to kick off a separate java project that will execute the rest calls. The end result is the final artifact will only contain the orginal project with the avro schema with its necessary dependencies excluding the code executing the REST calls along with any of its dependencies, for example Spring.

Was wondering if a stack overflow member can please provide guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: I'd suggest you look at the https://github.com/hermannpencole/nifi-swagger-client which allows you to run Nifi API requests as part of a maven plugin, If you link to the deploy phase of the maven build it should allow you to publish the avro schem's.

Comment: This seems more the task for a build server like Jenkins or Gitlab.

Comment: @Gimby yeah, true. Due to the authentication complexity on my schema registry and limitation on the CICD server, a raw java approach is more feasible at the moment.